# Épreuve de mathématiques, épreuve de culture générale - pourquoi l'article est absent ?

Tags: articles

Dans les phrases du type - épreuve de français, épreuve de culture générale - pourquoi l'article est-il absent ? Pourquoi ne dit-on pas l'épreuve de la culture générale ?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Le candidat peut dire "*l'épreuve de culture générale*" en parlant de celle qu'il a passée, l'article défini supposant qu'une seule épreuve peut entrer dans la conversation. Mais l'organisateur d'un concours ou d'un examen soumet *une* épreuve après une autre, dans plusieurs organismes ou sur plusieurs années; il a donc coutume de dire "*épreuve*", ce qui sous-entend l'article indéfini ("*une épreuve*") plutôt que "*l'épreuve*". Il est vrai nénamoins que, dans ce cas particulier, l'usage de l'article défini pourrait également se comprendre, mais le fait est qu'il ne s'emploie pas.

2 - En ce qui concerne "*de la culture générale*", l'usage de l'article est ici incorrect: le "*de*" précédant une matière (concrète ou abstraite) est suivi du nom sans article: "*masque de fer*", "*livre de grammaire*", "*épreuve de mathématiques*".

Answer (score 0):

Réponse courte:

épreuve culturelle = épreuve de culture

Les deux sont possibles.

**Lorsqu'il n'y pas d'adjectif**, la plupart du temps le **de** tient lieu d'adjectif.

Masque **de fer** puisque le mot fer dans son usage ordinaire n'a pas une forme qui correspond à un adjectif. Masque ferreux serait un masque qui contient du fer, expliqué pour les chimistes....

Si vous prenez un bain de lait, c'est parce qu'un bain laitier fait bizarre et correspondrait à un bain à base de lait.....

Par contre, si vous dites: C'est une épreuve de la culture générale de l'adolescent...la culture générale va avec adolescent, donc, il faut de la culture...puisqu'il s'agit de celle-là en particulier.

- C'était une **épreuve de culture**. [fonctionne **comme** un adjectif]
- C'était une épreuve **de la** culture des adolescents. [la culture générale que possède les adolescents [possessif]

Comment: C'était une véritable épreuve de culture (que) de faire face à X. Pas du tout ambigu..OU: épreuve culturelle.

Comment: @Fólkvangr une épreuve de culture et épreuve culturelle, oui. Votre réponse n'explique rien du tout. Verre de vin, puisqu'il n'y a pas **d'adjectif. le mot vin tient lieu d'adjectif. verre de lait, aussi. etc. etc. etc. à non plus finir. Il est bien connu des traducteurs vers l'anglais que le substantif + de + substantif est très souvent une structure "adjectivisante".